# Does any new version of iptables support 64bit mark target?

Tags: iptables

I'm using iptables v1.4.21, which doesn't accept 64 bit mark targets. 
Is there a newer version that is supposed to support 64 bit marks?

Edit:

```
$ uname -a
Linux sindhu 3.19.0-28-generic #30-Ubuntu SMP Mon Aug 31 15:52:51 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ iptables -I INPUT -s 6.6.6.6 -j MARK --set-xmark 1234567812345678/0xffffffffffffffff
MARK: Could not determine whether revision 2 is supported, assuming it is.
MARK: Could not determine whether revision 2 is supported, assuming it is.
iptables v1.4.21: MARK: bad mark value for option "--set-xmark", or out of range.
```

Comment: Why do you think, that's not supported? - MARK target: https://lwn.net/Articles/89814/ `Use full 64bit mark on 64bit archs`

Answer (score 2):

Support for 64bit marks should be supported since `iptables-1.2.10` on 64-bit machines. But it doesn't work, at least not in the latest version (`1.4.21-2ubuntu2` and kernel `4.2.0-18`).

---

From the [Changelog](https://lwn.net/Articles/89814/)

> iptables v1.2.10 Changelog
>    ====================================================================== 
>   This version requires kernel >= 2.4.4
>   This version recommends kernel >= 2.4.18
>
> Bugs Fixed from 1.2.9:
>
> - physdev match: fix new structure layout for kernel > 2.6.0-test8    [ Bart De Schuymer ]
> - Better 64bit / 32bit split architecture detection
> - IPv6 LOG target: Fix compiler warnings on 64bit
> - LOG target: Fix compiler warnings on 64bit
> - IPv6 MARK target: Use full 64bit mark on 64bit archs
> - **MARK target: Use full 64bit mark on 64bit archs**
> - SAME target: Fix 64bit/32bit splitarch problems
> - ULOG target: Fix 64bit/32bit splitarch problems
> - conntrack match: Fix 64bit/32bit splitarch problem
> - IPv6 limit match: Fix 64bit/32bit splitarch problem
> - limit match: Fix 64bit/32bit splitarch problem
> - IPv6 mark match: Use full 64bit mark on 64bit archs
> - mark match: Use full 64bit mark on 64bit archs
> - owner match: Fix compiler warnings on 64bit     [ Martin Jofsefsson ]
> - connbytes match: Fix signedness / unsigned issue    [ Martin Josefsson ]
> - connlimit match: Fix '/0' netmask   [ David Ahern ]
> - ipv6 owner match: fix possibly not zero terminated string
> - helper match: fix possibly not zero terminated string
> - recent match: fix possibly not zero terminated string   [ Karsten Desler ]
> - ICMP match: fix '--icmp-type any' case  [ Harald Welte ]
> - CONNMARK target: major update (add mark/mask matching)  [ Henrik Nordstrom ]
> - DSCP target: Fix cosmetic help message problem      [ Maciej Soltysiak ]
> - string match: Fix iptables-save/restore for ascii strings with spaces   [ Michael Rash ]
> - ip(6)tables-restore: Make sure matches are used in the same order   [ Martin Josefsson ]
> - ip(6)tables-restore: Fix '--verbose' option
> - ip(6)tables-restore: Add '--test' option
> - ip(6)tables-restore: Complain about missing 'COMMIT'    [ Martin Josefsson ]
> - ip(6)tables-restore: Allow embedding of quote character in quoted strings   [ Michael Rash ]
> - libipq: Protect against spoofed queue messages (check if sender is kernel)  [ Harald Welte ]

Comment: I saw this site and thought it's supported. But my machine is 64 bit and I can't configure a 64 bit mark on it.